# Iniciando em Python

Tags: python

Fiz um programa para ver qual time fica com a última vaga de rebaixamento no campeonato brasileiro.

No final quando coloco para ordenar os resultados, saem logicamente por resultados. Como voltar para string inicial (ex: ao invés de 22, aparecer "time18")?

Sei que não é a melhor forma de fazer o código mas foi o que meu conhecimento proporcionou.

```
time18 = input('Entre com o time 18° posição: ')
time17 = input('Entre com o time 17° posição:')
time16 = input('Entre com o time 16° posição:')
time15 = input('Entre com o time 15° posição:')
time14 = input('Entre com o time 14° posição:')
time13 = input('Entre com o time 13° posição:')
time12 = input('Entre com o time 12° posição:')

var18  = float(input("pontuação dos ultimos 5 jogos do %s: " %(time18)))
var17 = float(input("pontuação dos ultimos 5 jogos do %s: " %(time17)))
var16 = float(input("pontuação dos ultimos 5 jogos do %s: " %(time16)))
var15 = float(input("pontuação dos ultimos 5 jogos do %s: " %(time15)))
var14 = float(input("pontuação dos ultimos 5 jogos do %s: " %(time14)))
var13 = float(input("pontuação dos ultimos 5 jogos do %s: " %(time13)))
var12 = float(input("pontuação dos ultimos 5 jogos do %s: " %(time12)))

P18 = (var18 / 15)
P17 = (var17 / 15)
P16 = (var16 / 15)
P15 = (var15 / 15)
P14 = (var14 / 15)
P13 = (var13 / 15)
P12 = (var12 / 15)

J = float(input('Quantidades de jogos que faltam para a competição terminar: '))

JF = J*3

PF18 = JF*P18
PF17 = JF*P17
PF16 = JF*P16
PF15 = JF*P15
PF14 = JF*P14
PF13 = JF*P13
PF12 = JF*P12

resultados = PF18, PF17 , PF16 , PF15 ,PF14, PF13,PF12 
resultados_ordenados = sorted(resultados)

print (resultados_ordenados)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como está começando, a primeira dica é [usar nomes melhores para as variáveis](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad). Por exemplo, `var18` é um nome genérico demais, que não diz nada sobre o mesmo, talvez `pontos` ou `pontuacao` seja melhor.

Como você está guardando o mesmo tipo de informação várias vezes (nome e pontuação de vários times), é melhor usar uma [lista](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list), em vez de ter várias variáveis. No caso, cada elemento da lista terá as informações de um time, e para isso podemos usar [tuplas](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple).

Uma forma de fazer seria:

```
times = [] # lista dos times
for i in range(12, 19):
    nome_time = input(f'Entre com o time da {i}° posição: ')
    pontos = int(input(f"pontuação dos últimos 5 jogos do {nome_time}: "))
    times.append( (nome_time, pontos) ) # cada time é uma tupla contendo o nome e a pontuação
```

Eu usei [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) para formatar as mensagens, que estão disponíveis desde o Python 3.6, mas se estiver usando uma versão anterior, pode trocar para:

```
nome_time = input('Entre com o time da {}° posição: '.format(i))
pontos = int(input("pontuação dos últimos 5 jogos do {}: ".format(nome_time)))
```

No código acima, `times` começa com uma lista vazia (`[]`), e eu faço um `for` no  [`range(12, 19)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) (o primeiro número é incluso e o segundo não, então ele vai iterar pelos números 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 e 18).

Em seguida, eu leio as informações do time: o nome e a pontuação. Repare que troquei [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) por [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int). Usar `float` faz mais sentido quando você pode ter números com casas decimais, mas pontuação de times de futebol sempre são números inteiros (não tem como um time ficar com 10,47 pontos).

Depois, para adicionar as informações na lista, eu uso o método `append`, e como parâmetro eu passo uma tupla contendo o nome e a pontuação. Repare que há um par de parênteses que parece redundante, mas não é. Sem esses parênteses ficaria:

```
times.append(nome_time, pontos)
```

E isso dá erro porque estamos passando dois parâmetros para `append`, mas ele só aceita um. Ao colocar `times.append( (nome_time, pontos) )`, estou indicando que o que eu quero adicionar é `(nome_time, pontos)`, que é uma tupla contendo o nome e a pontuação de um time.

Ou seja, no final `times` será uma lista contendo várias tuplas, sendo que cada tupla contém o nome do time e sua respectiva pontuação.

---

Para os jogos que faltam, também troquei `float` por `int`, pois a quantidade de jogos também é um número inteiro:

```
jogos_que_faltam = int(input('Quantidades de jogos que faltam para a competição terminar: '))
```

E para os cálculos, basta percorrer a lista de times e criar outra lista com o resultado das contas:

```
pf = [] # não entendi o que é "PF", então deixei com esse nome mesmo
for time in times:
    # time[0] é o nome do time, time[1] é a pontuação
    pf.append( (time[0],  (time[1] / 15) * jogos_que_faltam * 3 ) )
```

Bom, eu disse para dar nomes melhores para as variáveis, mas como eu não entendi o que é `PF`, eu não sei qual seria um nome melhor para ela.

De qualquer forma, `pf` também é uma lista, contendo o resultado da conta para cada time. Confesso que não entendi a lógica dessas contas, mas de qualquer forma eu fiz o mesmo cálculo aqui.

Para cada time, eu crio outra tupla contendo o nome (`time[0]`) e o resultado da conta (`time[1]` é a pontuação que foi lida no primeiro `for`, e eu uso este valor para fazer as contas).

Ao final deste *loop*, `pf` será uma lista, na qual cada elemento é uma tupla contendo o nome do time e o resultado das contas. Para ordená-la pelo resultado, basta fazer:

```
resultados = sorted(pf, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(resultados) # imprime [ ('time 1', valor), ('time 2', valor), etc... ]
```

O segundo parâmetro da [função `sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) é um [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html?highlight=lambda#small-functions-and-the-lambda-expression) indicando o que vai ser usado como critério para ordenar a lista. No caso, eu usei `x[1]` (como cada elemento `x` da lista é uma tupla, eu pego o valor que está na posição 1, que no caso é o resultado das contas - lembrando que o nome do time está no índice zero, e o resultado da conta está no índice 1, por isso `x[1]`).

Se quiser uma lista contendo somente os valores (sem os nomes dos times), basta usar [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
# se quiser somente os valores
resultados_somente_valores = list(map(lambda x: x[1], resultados))
print(resultados_somente_valores)
```

E se quiser uma lista com somente os nomes dos times:

```
# se quiser somente os nomes
resultados_somente_nomes = list(map(lambda x: x[0], resultados))
print(resultados_somente_nomes)
```

Por fim, para saber qual time foi rebaixado, basta pegar o último valor da lista:

```
# último time
ultimo_time = resultados[-1]
print(ultimo_time)
print(f'time {ultimo_time[0]} foi rebaixado, resultado: {ultimo_time[1]}')
```

Listas [aceitam índices negativos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295), então `-1` corresponde ao último elemento da lista (`-2` é o penúltimo, `-3` é o antepenúltimo, etc).

Comment: Mano, ficou top demais, perfeito! Era o que eu tava pesquisando msm... Só que deu um probleminha... A lista ta retornando o time com mais pts, tentei mudar o  -1 p/ -7, mas gera o seguinte erro: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app2.py", line 16, in <module>
    ultimo_time = resultados[-7]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Dionatan Se deu erro com -7 é porque a lista não tem 7 elementos. Se quiser o primeiro da lista, use `resultados[0]`

Answer (score 0):

@Dionathan seja bem vindo a comunidade! com o tipo de variável que vc está usando não tem como, você precisa algum outro tipo de variável, eu usaria uma lista ou uma tupla, dê uma olhada nos [tipos de estrutura](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) de dados que existe no python.

```py
PF18 = (JF*P18, "Time 18") # ou PF18 = [JF*P18, "Time 18"]
# ...

resultados = PF18, PF17 , PF16 , PF15 ,PF14, PF13,PF12 
resultados_ordenados = sorted(resultados)

print (resultados_ordenados)
```

Answer (score 0):

O @hkotsubo me ajudou, segue o código, muito obrigado msm!

```js
times = [] # lista dos times
for i in range(12, 13):
    nome_time = input(f'Entre com o time da {i}° posição: ')
    pontos = int(input(f"pontuação dos últimos 5 jogos do {nome_time}: "))
    ptsA = int(input(f"pontuação total do {nome_time}: "))
    times.append( (nome_time, pontos, ptsA) ) # cada time é uma tupla contendo o nome e a pontuação
    
jogos_que_faltam = int(input('Quantidades de jogos que faltam para a competição terminar: '))
    
pf = [] 
for time in times:
    # time[0] é o nome do time, time[1] é a pontuação
    pf.append( (time[0],  (time[1] / 15) * jogos_que_faltam * 3 + time[2]) )
    
    resultados = sorted(pf, key=lambda x: x[1])
    
    # se quiser somente os nomes
    resultados_somente_nomes = list(map(lambda x: x[0], resultados))
    print(resultados_somente_nomes)
    
    # último time
    ultimo_time = resultados[0]
    print(f'O {ultimo_time[0]} foi rebaixado: {ultimo_time[1]}')
```